# Embedding vector images

Tags: feature-request, images

Many modern browsers can without trouble interpret vector images, like [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). Is it possible to add support for these?

**Edit:**
As pointed out by Rahul Narain in the comments, the request for SVG support is the highest voted one, see [here](http://imgur.userecho.com/). I have just added mine, if you feel like you would benefit from SVG pictures, consider adding [your vote](http://imgur.userecho.com/topic/23630-svg-support/).

Comment: Wow, that title totally fooled me as an accidental post on meta instead of the main site.

Comment: StackExchanges uses Imgur to host images. On [Imgur's suggestion site](http://imgur.userecho.com/), the [request for SVG support](http://imgur.userecho.com/topic/23630-svg-support/) is the highest voted one, so it might actually happen. You could go add your vote there.

Comment: @RahulNarain I just did, thank you for the link!

Comment: Right, forget I asked...

Comment: I tried to up-vote using the links, but the `imgur` forum is said to be in "read-only mode".